# Visual Studio SP1 error: silverlight_sdk.msi is unavailable

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to install the SP1 for Visual Studio 2010. I first installed the beta and it worked fine. Then I used the web platform installer to install the SQL CE Compact 4, which I assume installed the full SP1 after (this installation took over 12 hours, so I canceled it). The web platform installer told me that SP1 and Silverlight 4 was installed.

Visual Studio tells me SP1 was partially installed. So I downloaded the installer from the site and now it gives me this error:

`Microsoft Silverlight 4 SDK - The feature you are trying to use is on a network resorce that is unavailable. Seeking application package 'silverlight_sdk.msi'`.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: This is just SO painful. You're also going to have to get the RiaServices.msi. There are multiple versions of that. You need WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP1 from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14880

Answer (score 132, accepted):

It's because Silverlight 4 isn't bundled with SP1 (apparently). Download Silverlight 4 tools, extract and point the SP1 error dialog to silverlight_sdk.msi. Should resolve it.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b3deb194-ca86-4fb6-a716-b67c2604a139&displaylang=en

Comment: I am following your instructions and see what will happen

Comment: I downloaded it but cannot find where the silverlight_sdk.msi folder is !

Comment: @tugberk_ugurl You can extract the contents of Silverlight4_Tools.exe using something like 7-Zip.

Comment: You can also extract the installation package by running the following in a command window: 'Silverlight4_Tools.exe /createlayout <path>'. Replace '<path>' with a temporary folder of your choice.

Comment: I used WinRAR to open Silverlight4_Tools.exe and extract silverlight_sdk.msi from it.

Comment: I had problems with other missing MSIs so I downloaded the sp1 ISO from the following link, extracted it using WinRAR, and was able to locate the MSIs in the extracted files: [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210710)

Comment: Same for me, extracted with 7zip and located the msi file

Comment: what seems to be happening is that Silverlight4_tools.exe creates temp folders that have no security info, and so it ends up not being able to access them. opening the file with winrar and manually extracting the contents, and then pointing the VS2kSP1 installer at the folder seems to have worked.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem you have to follow these steps:

1. Download "Microsoft Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010", but do not install.
2. Rename the downloaded installer file "Silverlight4_Tools.exe" to "Silverlight4_Tools.rar".
3. Extract the .rar file using tools like [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip).
4. You can find the file silvelright_sdk.msi in the extracted files.
5. Go back to your Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installer. If you are still on the error window, click the browse button to browse and choose the silvelright_sdk.msi from the folder where you extracted the files.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the offline installer and it worked fine.

Comment: Offline installer has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

After the execution of the web installer you will notice that a new directory has been created on the root of your C drive.
It would be a directory named like C:\961adfde6904297e47d06caaccf530. If you have many of those "strange named" directories you have to check the date modified and select the most recent. Inside that directory you will find the silverlight_sdk.msi file.

This is the file that is needed to be pointed by the "Use source" field of the "Microsoft Silver Light 4 SDK" installation error message.

Going on the installation, you may need the MSI file of the "[WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) [RIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application) Services v1.0 SP1". You can download it from *[WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP1 for Silverlight 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=14880)*.

And then you can again point it to your error message.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following link and it worked...

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7335

Comment: This should be a comment, besides which, posting links to external sites without any real explanation is just bad.

Comment: You should include in your answer the important parts of the page you are linking, and include the link as reference. That makes your answer more useful. Also, sometimes websites stop being online, and that will  make your answer useless

Comment: This link worked. It points to: Microsoft® Silverlight™ 4 SDK direct from the MS site. And i renamed it to .rar and extracted the msi and pointed it to it and it worked. Thanks.